# Key value pair is not being set, if undefined, but has a default value

Tags: javascript, object, foreach

I have an object with various key values (simplified):

```
const params = {
  dev: {
    api: {},
    iot: {},
  },
  test: {
    api: {},
    iot: {},
  }
};
```

That I want to populate through an `Object.keys().forEach` function:

```
Object.keys(params).forEach(key => {
  params[key].iot.keyName = `/firstURL/`;
  params[key].api.anotherKeyName = `/url/var2`;
});
```

At the moment, this populates as expected, but if I remove the keys (API/IOT) from the params object, I get an `undefined` error.

My thought from that was to check if the key was defined first and if not (which is actually never will be), use a default value:

```
Object.keys(params).forEach(key => {
  params[key].iot.keyName = params[key].iot.keyName || `/firstURL/`;
  params[key].api.anotherKeyName = params[key].api.anotherKeyName || `/url/var2`;
});
```

My reason for removing the keys out of the `params` object, is that they're always generated on the fly (dependent on what env you're in).

Why am I getting a `keyName` is undefined error, when I'm checking if it exists, and if not, assign a value to it?

Many thanks.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: *"...but if I remove the keys (API/IOT) from the params object, I get an undefined error."* When and how are you removing the keys (which is to say, the properties)? Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)).

Comment: Apologies, added :)

Comment: `params[key].iot` does not exist, so you are trying to access a property of an undefined object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> At the moment, this populates as expected, but if I remove **the keys (API/IOT)** from the params object, I get an undefined error.

*(my emphasis)*

Of course. Your code doesn't in any way check to make sure they're there first. To do that:

```
Object.keys(params).forEach(key => {
  if (params[key].iot) params[key].iot.keyName = `/firstURL/`;
  if (params[key].api) params[key].api.anotherKeyName = `/url/var2`;
});
```

---

Side note: You might look at [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values), added in ES2017 but fully polyfillable:

```
Object.values(params).forEach(entry => {
  if (entry.iot) entry.iot.keyName = `/firstURL/`;
  if (entry.api) entry.api.anotherKeyName = `/url/var2`;
});
```

Comment: I would recommend using ternary operator all the way:
params[key].iot ? params[key].iot.keyName : `/firstUrl/`

Comment: @LordAlpaca: And I wouldn't. Nor the `&&` version. :-)

Comment: Many thanks for your reply @T.J.Crowder, just when I think I understand accessing key/values... The values are actually generated on the fly, we could assume that those keys will never exist and will always need to be created first. Is there a suitable way to adapt this to your above check? Many thanks.

Comment: @Ben: I'm not 100% sure I know what you mean by "we could assume that those keys will never exist," but if you mean it literally, then: ``params[key].iot = {keyName: `/firstURL/`};`` (and the equivalent for the other one). That creates a property called `iot` on the entry and assigns it an object as its value; the object will have `keyName` on it.

Comment: ^ That works perfectly @T.J.Crowder, thank you once again :)

Answer (score 1):

> **Why am I getting a keyName is undefined error, when I'm checking if it
>   exists, and if not, assign a value to it?**

You aren't getting a message that `keyName` is `undefined`. If you look closely, the message says `Cannot read property 'keyName' of undefined"`.

```js
const params = {
  dev: {},
  test: {}
};

Object.keys(params).forEach(key => {
  params[key].iot.keyName = params[key].iot.keyName || `/firstURL/`;
  params[key].api.anotherKeyName = params[key].api.anotherKeyName || `/url/var2`;
});
```

**It's not complaining about `keyName`.** It's complaining that you can't read that property on something else that is `undefined` - that something is `iot`.

You are checking to see if `keyName` exists and setting a default for it if it doesn't, but that's not the issue. **The issue is that `iot` doesn't exist.**

---

You get the error because, while you can create a new property simply by assigning a value to it, you can't access a property on a non-existent property and that's what you are doing with:

```
params[key].iot.keyName = `/firstURL/`;
```

If `iot` doesn't exist, `iot.keyName` can't be accessed.

To illustrate:

```js
var obj = {};

obj.key1 = "foo";        // works
obj.key2.subKey = "bar"; // fails because key2 doesn't exist so bar can't be created on it
```

You'll need to add some checks to see if the property exists before accessing properties of the property. Here's an example:

```js
var obj = {};

obj.key1 = "foo";        // works

if(obj.key2){
  obj.key2.subKey = "bar"; // works when key2 exists
} else {
  obj.key2 = {};           // Create the key
  obj.key2.subKey = "bar"; // Now, you can access it and make sub-keys
}

console.log(obj);
```

A simple way to think about it is with an analogy of generations of people.

- `params` is the first generation
- `iot` is the second generation (a child of `params`)
- `keyName` is the third generation ( a child of `iot` and a grandchild
  of `params`)

As in the real world, you can't babysit for your grandchild if you don't have any children. The children must come first. Your code attempts to work with a grandchild when there are no children yet.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My guess is then I've misunderstood using default values? `params[key].iot.keyName = params[key].iot.keyName || `/firstURL/`;` 

I understood that it doesn't exist, and so to assign a default value to that property if it doesn't?

Comment: @Ben That is correct only if `iot` already exists. But, if `iot` doesn't exist, you can't access `keyName` to set a default value for it. In other words, you can't create many levels of properties/keys all at once. They have to be created one level at a time.